# How to remove the tags from the xml

Tags: xml, filter, tags

Hello guys I using this code to grab the certain text

my problem is how do I grab just the text not the tags.
see below the code

```
xmlExportDoc = "C:\Test\ep.xml"
Dim xmldoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument
Dim xmlInvTitle1 As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
Set xmldoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
xmldoc.async = False
xmldoc.Load (xmlExportDoc)
Set xmlInvTitle1 = xmldoc.SelectNodes("//exchange-documents/exchange-document[0]/bibliographic-data/invention-title[1]").Item(0)

innovationTitleEN = xmlInvTitle1.xml
MsgBox innovationTitleEN
```

I get this result

```
<invention-title lang="de">read this line too</invention-title>
```

how do I remove the tags

I just want to have in the alert

```
read this line too
```

here is my XML

see link below

http://pastebin.com/Cap78FS1

thank you all Stackoverflow members in advance

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
innovationTitleEN = xmlInvTitle1.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried...

```
innovationTitleEN = xmlInvTitle1.InnerXML
```